# Mustache.js - Rendering only a limited number of array objects

Tags: mustache

I recently inherited this from another developer, and what was left behind for me has me stumped.

I am trying to build a set-up in which the first 3 objects in my JSON array are rendered on the page via mustache, then with a click, the next 3 load, and so forth.  Where I'm stuck right now is just figuring out how to make Mustache only render 3 objects.  I've done quite a bit of searching but I can't seem to find the syntax.

There is no code associated with the 'load-more' button yet.  I figured I'd start with the first part of the puzzle.

Alternatively, is there a better solution than mustache for this kind of layout?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="bios"></div>

<!-- JSON data -->
<div id="divInsightsData">
    <script>
    var prof_data = {
        bios: [
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 1",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 2",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 3",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 4",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 5",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 6",
                office: "New York"
            }
        ]};

    var template="{{#bios}}<div class='bio'><p class='author-details'>{{name}}</p><p class='author-details'>{{title}}</p><p class='author-details'>{{office}}</p></div>{{/bios}}";
    var html = Mustache.render(template, prof_data);
    $("#bios").append(html);

    </script>
</div> 

<a href="#" class="load-more">Load More</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only the first 3 elements of the array are what you're presenting, then the entire array is *not* your view-model and you should *not* pass it to mustache.

It is possible to pass a function to Mustache for this, but it is not the "Mustache Way"

**The less logic you have in your mustache templates, the more debug-able and maintainable they are.** This is the strong point of using Mustache for templating. They should accept your view-model as is and work with that, rather than apply logic to it and try to manipulate it.

Let's say you have your

```
var prof_data = {
        bios: [
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 1",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 2",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 3",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 4",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 5",
                office: "New York"
            },
            {   name: "John Smith",
                title: "Title 6",
                office: "New York"
            }
        ]};
```

You can create a:

```
var prof_data_viewmodel = {
        bios: prof_data.bios.slice(0,3)
    };
```

And pass that to Mustache instead

Comment: Thanks.  In isolation, this worked.  It did answer my question of how to isolate certain array objects.  I'm still having a lot of problems with it though, which may just relate to my own lack of familiarity with JSON.  When I have this all trigger on document ready, it works fine.  However, as soon as I put it inside a function to activate on click, everything stops working.  Regardless, thank you for the help.