# Rendering Limited Number of Object in Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am GETing a nested JSON object that I want to render on a HTML page. The length and content of the object can vary and I want to show a part of it. I do not know how to do it using Mustache.js

My object looks like this:

```
{ "success": [
  {
    "stopID": "123",
    "stopName": "ABC",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineRef": "3",
        "destinationID": "987",
        "destinationName": "DEF",
        "arrivals": [
          1490279520000,
          1490279460000,
          1490280180000
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stopID": "331",
    "stopName": "TVC",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineRef": "3",
        "destinationID": "128",
        "destinationName": "NJH",
        "arrivals": [
          1490279160000,
          1490280180000
        ]
      },
      {
        "lineRef": "3V",
        "destinationID": "361",
        "destinationName": "KOI",
        "arrivals": [
          1490280360000
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stopID": "3601",
    "stopName": "LKG",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineRef": "3",
        "destinationID": "128",
        "destinationName": "ABC",
        "arrivals": [
          1490279040000,
          1490280360000,
          1490280180000,
          1490280180000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

I want to display maximum of two arrivals, how can I put a limit there.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428497/mustache-js-rendering-only-a-limited-number-of-array-objects) but it is not much help. My code is like this:

```
<script id="#timetables" type="text/template">
    {{#success}}
    <tr style = "">
       <th colspan="3" style="padding-left:25px;">{{stopName}}<span><sup style="padding-left:5px;font-weight:100"><small>{{stopID}}</sup></span></th>
       </tr>
       {{#lines}}
       <tr class="line-row">

          <td class="" style="border:none;width:10%;">{{lineRef}}</td>
          <td class="" style="border:none;width:30%;">{{destinationName}}</td>
          <td class="" style="border:none;width:60%;">{{arrivals}}</td>

        </tr>
        {{/lines}}



    {{/success}}
  </script>
```

Comment: MustacheJS is logic-less. It will render everything you give it unconditionally. Perhaps look at using `slice();` to create a subset of your data to display (this is non destructive).

Comment: Yes that is what I did for now. Sort of preprocessing the data before feeding it to mustache. Had to use nested for loops. Is there a better way than for to achieve this. I did not understand this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283776/iterate-through-json-array-with-mustache